# Troubles when I tried to run the gymnasium code in python3.11.3

Tags: python-3.x, box2d, openai-gym

Before this, I was trying to run the gymnasium, but the code(that I copied from the gymnasium document) couldn't work, saying that I needed to run `pip install gymnasium[box2d]`, but after I did so

```
`C:\Users\86178>pip install gymnasium[box2d]
Requirement already satisfied: gymnasium[box2d] in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jax-jumpy>=1.0.0 in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.2.0 in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.3.0 in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (4.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: farama-notifications>=0.0.1 in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (0.0.4)
Collecting box2d-py==2.3.5 (from gymnasium[box2d])
  Using cached box2d-py-2.3.5.tar.gz (374 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pygame==2.1.3 (from gymnasium[box2d])
  Using cached pygame-2.1.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (10.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: swig==4.* in c:\users\86178\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gymnasium[box2d]) (4.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: box2d-py
  Building wheel for box2d-py (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for box2d-py: filename=box2d_py-2.3.5-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl size=432969 sha256=ef9754c675eaa6b8c732cd174892fc7f16134d132ac75a393af75b7b0d35979e
  Stored in directory: c:\users\86178\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\ab\f1\0c\d56f4a2bdd12bae0a0693ec33f2f0daadb5eb9753c78fa5308
Successfully built box2d-py
Installing collected packages: box2d-py, pygame
  Attempting uninstall: pygame
    Found existing installation: pygame 2.4.0
    Uninstalling pygame-2.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pygame-2.4.0
Successfully installed box2d-py-2.3.5 pygame-2.1.3`
```

It still shows error of

```
PS D:\ProjectPython> & C:/Users/86178/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe d:/ProjectPython/GYM/example1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\86178\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\box2d\bipedal_walker.py", line 15, in <module>
    import Box2D
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Box2D'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ProjectPython\GYM\example1.py", line 2, in <module>
    env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode="human")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\86178\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\registration.py", line 755, in make
    env_creator = load_env_creator(env_spec.entry_point)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\86178\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\registration.py", line 553, in load_env_creator
    mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\86178\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\86178\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\box2d\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gymnasium.envs.box2d.bipedal_walker import BipedalWalker, BipedalWalkerHardcore
  File "C:\Users\86178\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\box2d\bipedal_walker.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise DependencyNotInstalled(
gymnasium.error.DependencyNotInstalled: Box2D is not installed, run `pip install gymnasium[box2d]`
```

why?

Comment: Have you seen that Windows is not officially supported? *We support and test for Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 on Linux and macOS. We will accept PRs related to Windows, but do not officially support it.* (https://pypi.org/project/gymnasium/) Maybe you try on a Linux or macOS system.